# jQuery TypeError: $("img").draggable(); is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Hello, I have been having a problem with this code for the last 3 hours and I'm hoping someone is gonna be able to help me out here.**

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("img").draggable();});
```

**HTML header**

```
<head>
    <title>Chess</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="default.js"></script>
</head>
```

**FireBug Error**

```
TypeError: $("img").draggable is not a function [Break On This Error] $("img").draggable();
```

**My code works perfectly on [codecademy.com](http://www.codecademy.com/) but when i try it on localhost or my server, i keep getting this error message. What am i doing wrong here?**

**Complete HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>Chess</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="default.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div id="board">
        <ul id="first_row">
            <li class="white_space"><img src="pieces/Rook_Black.png" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="pieces/Pawn_Black.png" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="pieces/Pawn_White.png" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="pieces/Rook_White.png" /></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="second_row">
            <li class="black_space"><img src="pieces/Knight_Black.png" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="pieces/Pawn_Black.png" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="pieces/Pawn_White.png" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="pieces/Knight_White.png" /></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="third_row">
            <li class="white_space"><img src="pieces/Bishop_Black.png" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="pieces/Pawn_Black.png" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="pieces/Pawn_White.png" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="pieces/Bishop_White.png" /></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="forth_row">
            <li class="black_space"><img src="pieces/Queen_Black.png" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="pieces/Pawn_Black.png" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="pieces/Pawn_White.png" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="pieces/King_White.png" /></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="fifth_row">
            <li class="white_space"><img src="pieces/King_Black.png" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="pieces/Pawn_Black.png" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="pieces/Pawn_White.png" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="pieces/Queen_White.png" /></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="sixth_row">
            <li class="black_space"><img src="pieces/Bishop_Black.png" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="pieces/Pawn_Black.png" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="pieces/Pawn_White.png" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="pieces/Bishop_White.png" /></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="seventh_row">
            <li class="white_space"><img src="pieces/Knight_Black.png" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="pieces/Pawn_Black.png" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="pieces/Pawn_White.png" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="pieces/Knight_White.png" /></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="eight_row">
            <li class="black_space"><img src="pieces/Rook_Black.png" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="pieces/Pawn_Black.png" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="#" /></li>
            <li class="black_space"><img src="pieces/Pawn_White.png" /></li>
            <li class="white_space"><img src="pieces/Rook_White.png" /></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Youre not loading jquery, only jquery-ui. jquery itself is not loaded by jquery-ui so you need 2 different `script` tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Presumably the reason it works on codecademy is that jQuery has already been loaded in order to present the codecademy page to you.

Comment: Now FireBug sends me this error : "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js"

Comment: Because 1.8.2 is the jQuery version number, not the jQueryUI version number. They are not in sync. Also, jquery-ui.min.js is in the separate `jqueryui` folder. Please double-check the URLs you were given. Actually, better copy-and-paste them. (Alternatively, you could look up the most up-to-date version numbers for each. It's also suggested to [leave off the `http:` part](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/).)

Comment: It works!! Thank you guys so much, i can finally start focusing on more important things.